# Codeigniter 4 query IF ISNULL

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I am migrating from Codeigniter 3 to Codeigniter 4 and the next query is problematic to me.

In Codeigniter 3, the query was:

```
$this->db->query("UPDATE myTable SET data = '$data', 
                    myData = IF ( ISNULL(myData), '$state', CONCAT('$state', '-', myData) ) 
                  WHERE id = '$id'");
```

I tried to change this with the next format:

```
$data = array(
    'myData' => "IF( ISNULL(myData), " . $state. ", CONCAT(" . $state. ", '-', myData')")
);
```

However, the function updates the content of `$myData` like a string `"IF( ISNULL(myData), " . stateOfExample. ", CONCAT(" . stateOfExample. ", '-', myData')"`.

I have looked into the CI4 documentation but I could not find the way to develop this query.
I find the way to do that with the where() CI function, but I think is not the best way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you put SQL functions in data, codeigniter won't understand that those are functions. It just adds them as string.

Put `IF`, `CONCAT`, `ISNULL` in sql and use data array just for variables.

```
$this->db->query("UPDATE myTable SET data = ?, 
    myData = IF ( ISNULL(myData), ?, CONCAT(?, '-', myData) ) 
    WHERE id = ?", array($data, $state, $state, $id));
```

Comment: This kind of structures works in Codeigniter 3, but as i said i am migrating to Codeigniter 4, that's not follow the Codeigniter queries structure

Comment: What do you mean by that? This is from the docs https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#query-bindings

Comment: You are right, this is a valid query structure in CI4, but it does not work to me